# can ERC20 token implements private transfers functions

Tags: solidity, contract-design, tokens, erc-20, exchanges

I know Golem Network Token is **not** implementing the approve() allowance() and transferFrom() functions. Thus, GNT is partially compliant to ERC20 standard.

I would like to go futher, and implement the transfer() function as **private()**.

This way, it would be impossible for the token holders to freely trade it (it would only be possible using a custom mechanism -- see below), but still possible to see the token in wallets.

Sample code would look like this:

```
contract CustomToken is ERC20 {

    public symbol = “TEST”
    public totalSupply = X;
    public balanceOf...

    //function approve() -- not implemented
    //function transferFrom() -- not implemented

    // first step: check that the caller is KYC
    function placeOrderBuy(int _amountToken, int _maxPrice ) external payable 
            returns(bool success); 

    // first step: check that the caller is KYC
    function placeOrderSell(int _amountToken, int _minPrice ) external 
            payable returns(bool success); 

    //run automatically every month, and transfer the tokens function 
    executeOrders() private returns(float newPrice);

    // triggers Transfer event 
    transfer(address _to, uint _value) private returns(bool success);
}
```

1. Would this be accepted as a partially compliant ERC20, like GNT is? Would wallets accept it?
2. I believe the above contract is working, but maybe there are some problems I didn't think of? What do you think?
3. if ERC20 is out of the table, I could just remove the transfer() function too, and implement the token transfer within the executeOrders() functions, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tools that handle / interact with a smart contract do so by using the encoded signature of the function interfaces. The signature is built from the canonical interface for the function, so

```
transfer(address,uint)
```

becomes canonical as

```
transfer(address,uint256)
```

and encoded as

```
0xa9059cbb
```

Adding `private` doesn't change the interface, so the encoding is the same, so the tools will be ignorant of the change. It should work fine.